# Run a setup without admin privilages

Tags: windows, windows-vista, installation

I have a setup program that I want to install to a local folder.  I also do not need it to write any settings to the registry.  On Vista, and maybe on Windows 7, executables named similar to setup or install require admin privileges, I would like to be able to run it without admin privileges, to make sure that it does not write to the registry.  Is there a way to force this type of mode, sort of in a sandbox?

Comment: This should be on http://superuser.com.

Comment: I think you'll find that it's not the filename that's the issue, it's what they try to do (e.g., requesting admin rights, writing to the registry, etc.). Doing it based on filename would be too easily circumvented (even if we *are* talking about Microsoft).

Comment: @danben & close voters: Writing setup programs isn't programming?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: *running* setup programs isn't programming.

Comment: @Halpo Is this your setup program, or somebody elses? If it's yours, you've come to the right place but we need more details. If it's somebody elses then this should migrate to superuser.com

Comment: This is someone elses.  I will move it over to superuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are producing the installer and using MSI, set bit 3 of PID_WORDCOUNT in the MSI package (per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252871/make-uac-optional-in-windows-installer-on-vista)).

The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192798/help-with-understanding-why-uac-dialog-pops-up-on-win7-for-our-application) is relevant if you are producing the installer but aren't using MSI - see [create a manifest that prevents elevation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: Adding a manifest to a file with a requestedExecutionLevel inhibits the auto elevation logic Vista and Windows 7 apply to applications they "guess" are legacy setup programs.