# Can I stop an executable from requesting UAC elevation?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, uac

I have an installer I'd like to run from a script.  The installer requests UAC elevation but it doesn't need elevation because I'm installing to a user directory.  Is there some way to run the installer so that it doesn't request UAC elevation?

The script is written in Python so I can access the Windows API through ctypes.

Changing the installer is not an option.

Comment: What installer is it?  This might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252871/make-uac-optional-in-windows-installer-on-vista

Comment: @John it's an exe created by Inno Setup.

Comment: [This superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it) appears to be relevang.

Comment: I've heard that the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit can disable UAC elevation for a specific executable.  However, while this doesn't involve modifying the executable, it does involve modifying the operating system so I'm guessing this isn't a good option for you.

Comment: Have you tried to run the installation under limited user account with UAC turned off or on XP/2003? The installer could be writing uninstall info into HKLM, and therefore requires elevation.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the enviromnet variable **__compat_layer** for your process to **RunAsInvoker**. Then you can run the executable without any UAC prompt.

You can use the Windows API function [SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: Norbert, could you do me a favour and post the same answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004310/bypassing-elevation-when-launching-a-new-process the system is complaining because I haven't accepted an answer :-)